# Slowdown issue if C function is placed in a separate file?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I am experiencing some strange slowdown issues with my program, written in C.

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
   Uint8 r;
   Uint8 g;
   Uint8 b;
   Uint8 alpha;
} COLOUR;

COLOUR get_colour(int r, int g, int b, int alpha) {
   COLOUR colour;

   colour.r = r;
   colour.g = g;
   colour.b = b;
   colour.alpha = alpha;

   return colour;
}
```

I then insert something like this in my main loop, just to reproduce my issue:

```
for (i = 0; i < 640 * 480; i++) {
   blue = get_colour(0, 0, 255, 255);
   yellow = get_colour(255, 255, 0, 255);
}
```

This works fine, no slowdowns yet.

BUT, if I move the code for my function *get_colour()* to a separate .C file (I prefer to store such functions in a library), I start getting slowdowns. Just the simple for-loop above causes my frame rate to drop from 100+ fps down to 70 fps.

Moving the code for my function *get_colour()* back to the same .C file as the rest of the code restores the speed back to normal.

What is causing this?

My compiler is GCC under MinGW, if that has anything to do with it.

Thank you very much for any answers.

Comment: It might be an issue with [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). If the function is in the same [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) then the compiler might be able to inline the function, but if the function is in another source file (and therefore another translation unit) then the compiler can't do that.

Comment: Do you really need such a function at all? Can you not define `const COLOUR blue = { 0, 0, 255, 255 };` before your loop?

Comment: @KerrekSB The colour function is just an example. Sorry if it over-complicates my question or draws attention away from it. I included it because that's where I discovered the problem I'm having. I have since then discovered that I can just have a function like this: `int return_something() { return 0; }` and call that in a for-loop a large number of times, and I will have the same slowdown issue. But ONLY if the function is placed in a separate .C file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you very much, I will look into that.

Comment: Just to confirm Joachim's comment, I tried to define your function using the `inline` modifier in a separate translation unit, and got an error saying: Function get_colour declared with inline must be defined in same module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly because of `inlining` vs not. There is a comment above that mentioned that using the `inline` keyword in the other file doesn't work.

What you need to do is define the inline functions in a `.h` file, and include it above `main()`. Don't forget to use the `-O` flag during compile to enable `inilining`.

In `bar.h`:

```
typedef struct {
   Uint8 r;
   Uint8 g;
   Uint8 b;
   Uint8 alpha;
} COLOUR;

inline COLOUR get_colour(int r, int g, int b, int alpha) {
   COLOUR colour;

   colour.r = r;
   colour.g = g;
   colour.b = b;
   colour.alpha = alpha;

   return colour;
}
```

In `foo.c`:

```
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    int i;
    COLOUR blue, yellow;
    for (i = 0; i < 640 * 480; i++) {
       blue = get_colour(0, 0, 255, 255);
       yellow = get_colour(255, 255, 0, 255);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to solve the issue I am having.